# One audio play at once Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, next.js

I'm using `react-use-audio-player` for my project and I need to play only one audio at a time. I have multiple audios in the same page. Currently, all the audios are pause when it's loading which is what I need. But while playing an audio and I click the next audio without pause, the first one is overlapping with each other. I added my code below for your reference. Appreciate if anyone could help me out.

Here my `pages/index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { AudioPlayerProvider } from 'react-use-audio-player'
import AudioPlayer from '../../../components/AudioPlayer'

const Home = () => {

  return (
    <>
     <ul>
      <li>
            <div className='color_c uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-flex-center uk-text-center'>
              <div>
                <AudioPlayerProvider>
                  <AudioPlayer file='../../../projectFolder/audio/c_chai-yi-ning_90s.mp3' playButton='/projectFolder/img/icon_play_c.svg' pauseButton='/projectFolder/img/icon_pause_c.svg' />
                </AudioPlayerProvider>
                <div className='uk-text-small'>Chai Yi Ning, 19</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
         <li>
            <div className='color_c uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-flex-center uk-text-center'>
              <div>
                <AudioPlayerProvider>
                  <AudioPlayer file='../../../projectFolder/audio/c_chai-yi-ning_90s.mp3' playButton='/projectFolder/img/icon_play_c.svg' pauseButton='/projectFolder/img/icon_pause_c.svg' />
                </AudioPlayerProvider>
                <div className='uk-text-small'>Ying Ming, 54</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
         <li>
            <div className='color_c uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-flex-center uk-text-center'>
              <div>
                <AudioPlayerProvider>
                  <AudioPlayer file='../../../projectFolder/audio/c_chai-yi-ning_90s.mp3' playButton='/projectFolder/img/icon_play_c.svg' pauseButton='/projectFolder/img/icon_pause_c.svg' />
                </AudioPlayerProvider>
                <div className='uk-text-small'>Lee Chong Wie, 29</div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </li>
     </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Here my `components/AudioPlayer.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useAudioPlayer } from 'react-use-audio-player'

const AudioPlayer = ({ file, playButton, pauseButton }) => {
  const { play, pause, ready, loading, playing } = useAudioPlayer({
    src: file,
    format: 'mp3',
    autoplay: false
  })

  const togglePlay = () => {
    if (playing) {
      pause()
    } else {
      play()
    }
  }

  if (!ready && !loading) return <div>No audio to play</div>
  if (loading) return <div>Loading audio</div>

  return (
    <>
      <img src={!playing ? playButton : pauseButton} onClick={togglePlay} className='uk-width-2-3' style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} />
    </>
  )
}

export default AudioPlayer
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding a ***lifecycle*** method will take care of the issue, each time the **component unmounts** the **return** is called, so if you are changing songs then the **return** block will check if audio is playing and pause the song and then the next song will play.

```
   import React,{useEffect} from 'react'

    useEffect(()=>{
    return (()=>{
    if (playing) {
      pause()} })
    },[file])
```

Comment: This doesn't help.

Comment: Your explanation too short. You should write down `playing` and `pause` functions. Not like that.